# Banana peel bruises after a hit

Tags: botany, fruit

When a banana fall on the floor or get a certain impact, the impact location gets darker (it bruises) after a certain amount of time. The darkening affects the peel as well as the fruit itself. Why does this happen?

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16523/what-exactly-makes-bananas-go-brown

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Thx :) I saw that but, I was wondering what is happening when the banana fall and not only the normal ripening process. From what I have read online, it seems that when a certain pressure is exerted on the peel, the cells are damaged and they release an enzyme that will make the ripening faster. Nevertheless, I am waiting for a technically detailed answer describing the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fruit is discolored in the first place because, when certain compounds are altered (oxidized), they turn brown.

In a banana (and most fruit) those compounds are *phenolic compounds*, and *polyphenoloxidase* is the thing that oxidizes them.

In an undamaged banana, the phenolic compounds and the polyphenoloxidase (that can turn them brown) are physically separated.

When the banana is crushed/dropped/etc, the structure of the banana is damaged so that the phenolic compounds and the polyphenoloxidase come into contact.  The polyphenoloxidase oxidizes the phenolic compounds, and you get that brownish color.

A nice summary (which links to a more detailed reference) can be found here: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-bruised-fruit-tu/